# how to present an UIImagePicker inside the camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

So what am I trying to do here is just to open the camera roll from within a custom camera overlayView. I implemented the custom camera overlayView, created a UIImagePickerController, and replaced the default overlay with my custom one. Then I created another instance of UIImagePickerController, set the sourceType to PhotoLibrary and tries to present it when a button on the overlayView is pressed.

The below error message shows when i press the button:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x14da5440> on <UINavigationController: 0x14e63760> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)select:(id)sender
{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

you need to use completion block for present one view controller when another view controller dismiss like following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

            [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                                  animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];
```